# how to re set the local Storage session in react native with Async Storage

Tags: react-native

i am using Async storage for store data
i am trying to set new cart list using Async storage but set item not wokring

how it is possiple to set this again

CallPI("POST", url, addtoGrid, LoginUserID, '', cart).then((response) => response.json()).then(responseJson =>{
// AsyncStorage.removeItem("AddToCart");
if(responseJson.CartList.le)

```
        this.setState({
          CartItem: responseJson.CartList,
          isLoading: false,
          TotalAmount: responseJson.TotalAmount
        })
        
           
          AsyncStorage.setItem("AddToCart", responseJson.CartList);
        
      
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(
          CommonActions.reset({
             
              routes: [
                  {
                      name: 'MyCart',
                  }
              ],
          })
      )
      })
```

Please any body can help me

Answer (score 1):

This will work

`AsyncStorage.setItem("AddToCart", responseJson.CartList);`

Just use `async/await` together and if `responseJson.CartList` is not a string type then use `JSON.stringify` to convert it.

Also, don't forget to parse it during `AsyncStorage.getItem` using `JSON.parse`.